# Is it possible to minimize all functions at Android Studio at once?

Tags: android-studio, ide

When working on a class with thousands of lines, minimizing some functions on the IDE makes it very handy to manage the code.

[image]

However, everytime we restart the IDE; or close the function: it will be re-opened again.

Is there a way to keep your 'minimizing' preferences?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can go to **Code > Folding > Collapse All**

In my case the short-cut is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHFT</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>.

Comment: Please mention how to revert.

Comment: This shortcut for me was used to create sections of comments

Comment: it's CTRL + SHIFT + numpad + to expand, and it's CTRL + SHIFT + numpad - to collapse

Answer (score 44):

(for windows Users)

Same time All Methods Collapse : <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHFT</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>

Same time All Methods Expand :<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHFT</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd>

(for Mac Users)

Same time All Methods Collapse : <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>SHFT</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>

Same time All Methods Expand :<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>SHFT</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd>

Comment: its not CTRL for mac users, instead you should use Command button in Mac OS

Comment: For Ubuntu users, the command for windows will do the needful.

Answer (score 14):

Here is the current way of expanding/collapsing in Windows...

[image]

Answer (score 3):

On **Mac OS** use these short keys:

> <kbd>Shift</kbd>  +  <kbd>Command</kbd>  + <kbd>-</kbd>

OR

> **Preferences-> Editor -> General-> code Folding**

Answer (score 3):

You can go to Setting->Editor->General->Code Folding->see checkbox then check show code folding outline,then apply.(Window OS)

Answer (score 3):

```
press --> 
on Windows & Linux
**to collapse --------> ctrl && shift && +
to expand ----------> ctrl && shift && -**

On Mac just use command instead of ctrl

Thank you
```

Have a look on there -> [Go there](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/keyboard-shortcuts)